C++ WebServer: NisseServer (Simle Server Class) Part-5
I think I made a mistake trying to start from the simplest version and working forward. This time I will present the final version, get all the fixes from here and incorperat them into the code, then I can reverse engineer the steps to get there.
The Parts of the server are:

NisseServer: Part-5
EventHandler: Part-4
Store: Part-3
JobQueue: Part-2
Pynt: Part-1

This post deals only with NisseServer.
Basically this holds the Store, EventHandler and JobQueue.
But also creates the actual Work objects that are passed to the JobQueue and registered with the EventHandler.
NisseServer.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_SERVER_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_SERVER_H

/*
 * NisseServer:
 *  Holds
 *      JobQueue:       This is a set of background thread to do any work set by the user.
 *      Store:          All stage information needed by the server.
 *                      Storage is thread safe assuming:
 *                          Only main thread adds new data.
 *                          Each thread only reads the object that it is acting on.
 *      EventHandler:   LibEvent wrapper.
 *                      It hold's all the information needed to processes a connection.
 *  The server puts appropriate "lambdas" into the Event Handler to processes a socket.
 */

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include "JobQueue.h"
#include "Store.h"
#include "EventHandler.h"
#include "Pynt.h"
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{

class NisseServer
{
    JobQueue                        jobQueue;
    Store                           store;
    EventHandler                    eventHandler;

    public:
        NisseServer(int workerCount = 1);

        void run();
        template<typename T>
        void listen(T listenerInit, Pynt& pynt);

    private:
        CoRoutine  createStreamJob(StreamData& info);
        CoRoutine  createAcceptJob(ServerData& info);
};

}

#endif

NisseServer.cpp
#include "NisseServer.h"
#include "EventHandler.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse;

NisseServer::NisseServer(int workerCount)
    : jobQueue{workerCount}
    , store{}
    , eventHandler{jobQueue, store}
{}

void NisseServer::run()
{
    eventHandler.run();
}

CoRoutine NisseServer::createStreamJob(StreamData& info)
{
    return CoRoutine
    {
        [&info](Yield& yield)
        {
            // Set the socket to work asynchronously.
            info.stream.getSocket().setReadYield([&yield](){yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreRead);return true;});
            info.stream.getSocket().setWriteYield([&yield](){yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreWrite);return true;});

            // Return control to the creator.
            // The next call will happen when there is data available on the file descriptor.
            yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreRead);

            try
            {
                PyntResult result = info.pynt->handleRequest(info.stream);
                while (result == PyntResult::More)
                {
                    yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreRead);
                    result = info.pynt->handleRequest(info.stream);
                }
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                std::cerr << "Pynt Exception:\n";
            }
            // We are all done
            // So indicate that we should tidy up state.
            yield(TaskYieldState::Remove);
        }
    };
}

CoRoutine NisseServer::createAcceptJob(ServerData& info)
{
    return CoRoutine
    {
        [&](Yield& yield)
        {
            // Set the socket to work asynchronously.
            info.server.setYield([&yield](){yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreRead);return true;});

            // Return control to the creator.
            // The next call will happen when there is data available on the file descriptor.
            yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreRead);

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    TAS::Socket          accept = info.server.accept(TAS::Blocking::No);
                    if (accept.isConnected())
                    {
                        // If everything worked then create a stream connection (see above)
                        // Passing the "Pynt" as the object that will handle the request.
                        // Note: The "Pynt" functionality is not run yet. The socket must be available to use.
                        eventHandler.add(TAS::SocketStream{std::move(accept)}, [&](StreamData& info){return createStreamJob(info);}, *info.pynt);
                    }
                    yield(TaskYieldState::RestoreRead);
                }
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                std::cerr << "Pynt Exception:\n";
            }
            // We are all done
            // So indicate that we should tidy up state.
            yield(TaskYieldState::Remove);
        }
    };
}

template<typename T>
void NisseServer::listen(T listenerInit, Pynt& pynt)
{
    TAS::Server  server{listenerInit};

    eventHandler.add(std::move(server), [&](ServerData& info){return createAcceptJob(info);}, pynt);
}

template void NisseServer::listen<TAS::SServerInfo>(TAS::SServerInfo listenerInit, Pynt& pynt);
template void NisseServer::listen<TAS::ServerInfo>(TAS::ServerInfo listenerInit, Pynt& pynt);

